# Search and replace string only if between two substrings

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I have the following string (Not in the DOM):

```
var string = '<g>
    <text font-family="Arial" font-size="72" font-weight="bold" style="stroke: rgb(255,255,255); stroke-opacity: 0;   stroke-miterlimit: 10; fill: rgb(0,0,0); fill-rule: nonzero; opacity: 1;" >
        <tspan x="-453.46" y="-7.92" font-size="104" style="stroke: rgb(255,255,255); stroke-opacity: 0;">J</tspan>
        <tspan x="-395.63" y="-7.92" font-size="104" style="stroke: rgb(255,255,255); stroke-opacity: 0;">A</tspan>
        <tspan x="-320.52" y="-7.92" font-size="104" style="stroke: rgb(255,255,255); stroke-opacity: 0;">N</tspan>
    </text>
</g>';
```

I would like to remove all occurrences of "stroke-opacity: 0;" inside the `<tspan></tspan>`

So it should not match if between `"<text" and ">"`

As far as I can tell this isn't possible with a single regex?

Comment: One will never know before one tries.

Comment: It _is possible_ with a single regex but not the best way to process html data

Comment: You can use css overrides. `tspan{ stroke-opacity: 1!important; }`.

Comment: I'm confused, Do you want to remove "stroke-opacity: 0;" from `tspan` but not if  `tspan` exist inside `text` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To do it using regular expressions, you can use the below regex:

```
/(<tspan.*?)(stroke-opacity: 0;)/gi
```

And, replace with `$1` to get rid of all the `stroke-opacity: 0` in the code (if present in a `<tspan>`) as shown in the sample below.

- `(<tspan.*?)` is the first capturing group, it makes sure that the `stroke-opacity is present within a``
- `(stroke-opacity: 0;)` is the second capturing group which matches `stroke-opacity: 0` wherever present
- `/gi` represent `global` and `case-insensitive` flags

```js
var string = '<g>' +
    '<text font-family="Arial" font-size="72" font-weight="bold" style="stroke: rgb(255,255,255); stroke-opacity: 0;   stroke-miterlimit: 10; fill: rgb(0,0,0); fill-rule: nonzero; opacity: 1;" >' +
        '<tspan x="-453.46" y="-7.92" font-size="104" style="stroke: rgb(255,255,255); stroke-opacity: 0;">J</tspan>' +
        '<tspan x="-395.63" y="-7.92" font-size="104" style="stroke: rgb(255,255,255); stroke-opacity: 0;">A</tspan>' +
        '<tspan x="-320.52" y="-7.92" font-size="104" style="stroke: rgb(255,255,255); stroke-opacity: 0;">N</tspan>' +
    '</text>' +
'</g>';
var res = string.replace(/(<tspan.*?)(stroke-opacity: 0;)/gi, "$1");
console.log(res);
```

Answer (score 0):

you need this: `$('text tspan').css('stroke-opacity', '');`

```js
$('text tspan').css('stroke-opacity', '');
console.dir( $('text').html() )
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<g>
    <text font-family="Arial" font-size="72" font-weight="bold" style="stroke: rgb(255,255,255); stroke-opacity: 0;   stroke-miterlimit: 10; fill: rgb(0,0,0); fill-rule: nonzero; opacity: 1;" >
        <tspan x="-453.46" y="-7.92" font-size="104" style="stroke: rgb(255,255,255); stroke-opacity: 0;">J</tspan>
        <tspan x="-395.63" y="-7.92" font-size="104" style="stroke: rgb(255,255,255); stroke-opacity: 0;">A</tspan>
        <tspan x="-320.52" y="-7.92" font-size="104" style="stroke: rgb(255,255,255); stroke-opacity: 0;">N</tspan>
    </text>
</g>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to remove `stroke-opacity` from all `tspan`, but not from `text` you can use the line below. There should be no reason to use a regex

`$("tspan").css('stroke-opacity','')`

```js
var s = '<g> <text font-family="Arial" font-size="72" font-weight="bold" style="stroke: rgb(255,255,255); stroke-opacity: 0; stroke-miterlimit: 10; fill: rgb(0,0,0); fill-rule: nonzero; opacity: 1;" > <tspan x="-453.46" y="-7.92" font-size="104" style="stroke: rgb(255,255,255); stroke-opacity: 0;">J</tspan> <tspan x="-395.63" y="-7.92" font-size="104" style="stroke: rgb(255,255,255); stroke-opacity: 0;">A</tspan> <tspan x="-320.52" y="-7.92" font-size="104" style="stroke: rgb(255,255,255); stroke-opacity: 0;">N</tspan> </text></g>'

var t = s.split('stroke-opacity:')
var finalStr = "";
for (i=0;i<t.length; i++)
{
  if(t[i].indexOf("<tspan") != -1){
    finalStr += t[i]
  }else {
    finalStr += t[i] + (i != (t.length - 1) ? "stroke-opacity:" : "")
  }
}

$('body').append(finalStr)
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Hi Carsten, I don't have the code in the DOM, I just have it as var string = "code", I assume I would have to add it to the DOM first?

Comment: @JohnSmith dont you think that would have been kinda important to include in your question?

Comment: I assumed it was enough to say that the code was a string. But I can see how that might not have been accurate enough.

Comment: @JohnSmith Take a look now